# How to make android app available for both tablets and pre 11 sdk?

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

**Update:** Adding this to manifest solved it:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Looks like google silently stopped listing newly submitted apps in tablet market that don't meet their "optimization tips".

<s>One of those "tips" is setting `minSdkVersion="11"`, which means losing 40% of their whole userbase who still run sdk 10 (hilarious).</s>

Can someone please suggest the least painful solution that would let me target both pre 11 SDK users and tablets, preferably without getting into multiple APK business.

If multiple APK is the way to go, then what is the best criteria to separate users on, so I can have a single version code at least.

(the app is fully compatible with all screen sizes and densities, currently targets `minSdkVersion="8"`)

Comment: One of those "tips" is setting minSdkVersion="11" => totally made up by you... That's not a tip

Comment: @Waza_Be Not sure what you mean, but I didn't make anything up. If you go to the "optimization tips" screen you see a link to http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions that says that the min sdk should be set to 11.

Comment: You are reading it wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading it wrong..

> At a minimum, check the  element to make sure that:
>
> targetSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher (14 or higher is
>   recommended), **OR** minSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or
>   higher.

I put 'or' in bold to make sure you read it...It was already in upper case, but was not enough  ;-)

Use targetSdkVersion to 17 and Support library as other people said.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) provided by Google. You can download it through the SDK manager. It requires a few changes to existing code (like using `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`, but it works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood the question. I don't want to use any SDK11 features, it already works fine on all tablets as is. I just want it to be listed in the market (which requires minSdkVersion="11" to be set in manifest it seems).

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like google silently stopped listing newly submitted apps in tablet market that don't meet their "optimization tips".

I'd be interested to know of any proof you have which supports that statement.

> One of those "tips" is setting minSdkVersion="11"

That is partially correct. Quoting the [Target Android versions properly](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions) section which you linked to in your comment to Waza_Be ...

> At a minimum, check the  element to make sure that:
>
> a. targetSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher (14 or higher is recommended), OR
>
> b. minSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher.
>
> c. If a maxSdkVersion attribute is declared, it must have a value of 11 or higher. Note that, in general, the use of maxSdkVersion is not recommended.

Note at the end of 'a' there is the word OR in capitals making 'b' unnecessary if 'a' is true (and we all know we can ignore 'c').

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) which has most of the functionality (if not more) of all sdk's > 11

The support library can be used on any device 2.2 and up

Comment: What would be minSdkVersion set to in this case, 11 or 8? Wouldn't it still fail the requirement is it's not 11? I don't need or use any new features from SDK 11.

Comment: @serg minimum SDK would be 8. And I am sure there are things you can use in the higher sdk's, many improvements were made, plus if you switch to using fragments you are future proofing your application

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this would let me overcome minSdkVersion="11" requirement if it will be still set to 8, and still not listed in tablet market?

Comment: You do not need to set the minSDk to >11 for it to show in the market for tablets. if its not showing its because of some permission in your manifest that the tablet does not have. The support library is what you use for backwards compatability when you want to use newer API's on older devices

Comment: If you do not care about optimizing your app with the support library (which would be big mistake) then figure out what manifest permission is causing your tablet not to be able to download it. Or post your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Google play is a unified market place for both phones and tablets. When a device visits the Google Play, it reports api version and capabilities (hardware), so the market only shows apps matching the provided criteria. If your app is not compatible with a device it will not show up.

Up to version 2.x (api 10) the same code was used for both tablets and phones. Then version 3.x (api 11-13) was just for tablets and then version 4.x (api 14) was again unified.

So we have 2.x tablets, 3.x tablets and 4.x tablets. Use minSdkVersion to declare up to which version your app supports.